# Match and Rearrange values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below:

```
    A Country  price1 A Country  price2 B Country  price1 B Country  price2 C Country  price1
0   19-12-04   0.0    19-12-05   1.7    19-12-05   2.6    19-12-06   3.2    19-12-05   0.1
1   19-12-03   1.5    19-12-04   1.7    19-12-04   2.6    19-12-05   3.2    19-12-04   0.1 
2   19-12-02   1.5    19-12-03   1.7    19-12-03   2.6    19-12-04   3.1    19-12-03   0.1
3   19-12-01   1.5    19-12-02   1.8    19-12-02   2.7    19-12-03   3.2    19-12-02   0.1
4   19-11-29   1.5    19-12-01   1.7    19-11-29   2.6    19-12-02   3.2    19-12-01   0.1
5   19-11-28   1.6    19-11-29   1.7    19-11-28   2.6    19-11-29   3.1    19-11-29   0.1
6   19-11-27   1.6    19-11-28   1.7    19-11-27   2.6    19-11-28   3.2    19-11-28   0.1
7   19-11-26   1.6    19-11-27   1.7    19-11-26   2.6    19-11-27   3.2    19-11-27   0.2
8   19-11-25   1.5    19-11-26   1.7    19-11-25   2.6    19-11-26   3.2    19-11-26   0.2
9   19-11-24   1.5    19-11-25   1.7    19-11-22   2.6    19-11-25   3.2    19-11-25   0.2
10  19-11-22   1.5    19-11-24   1.7    19-11-21   2.6    19-11-22   3.1    19-11-24   0.2
```

Each Country columns has different row values.
Now, I want to match and rearrange values by date. And I want to replace the blank by "?" mark. The result that I want is like below:

```
    A Country  price1 A Country  price2 B Country  price1 B Country  price2 C Country  price1
0   19-12-06   ?      19-12-06   ?      19-12-06   ?      19-12-06   3.2    19-12-06   ?  
1   19-12-05   ?      19-12-05   1.7    19-12-05   2.6    19-12-05   3.2    19-12-05   0.1
2   19-12-04   0.0    19-12-04   1.7    19-12-04   2.6    19-12-04   3.1    19-12-04   0.1
3   19-12-03   1.5    19-12-03   1.7    19-12-03   2.6    19-12-03   3.2    19-12-03   0.1 
4   19-12-02   1.5    19-12-02   1.8    19-12-02   2.7    19-12-02   3.2    19-12-02   0.1
5   19-12-01   1.5    19-12-01   1.7    19-12-01   ?      19-12-01   ?      19-12-01   0.1
6   19-11-29   1.5    19-11-29   1.7    19-11-29   2.6    19-11-29   3.1    19-11-29   0.1
7   19-11-28   1.6    19-11-28   1.7    19-11-28   2.6    19-11-28   3.2    19-11-28   0.1
8   19-11-27   1.6    19-11-27   1.7    19-11-27   2.6    19-11-27   3.2    19-11-27   0.2
9   19-11-26   1.6    19-11-26   1.7    19-11-26   2.6    19-11-26   3.2    19-11-26   0.2
10  19-11-25   1.5    19-11-25   1.7    19-11-25   2.6    19-11-25   3.2    19-11-25   0.2
11  19-11-24   1.5    19-11-24   1.7    19-11-24   ?      19-11-24   ?      19-11-24   0.2
12  19-11-23   ?      19-11-23   ?      19-11-23   ?      19-11-23   ?      19-11-23   ?
13  19-11-22   1.5    19-11-22   ?      19-11-22   2.6    19-11-22   3.1    19-11-22   ?
14  19-11-21   ?      19-11-21   ?      19-11-21   2.6    19-11-21   ?      19-11-21   ?
```

Sorry, I am a complete novice at coding. Column name is not important to me, 
So, Alternative result I want is:

```
    A Country  price1 price2 price1 price2 price1
0   19-12-06   ?      ?      ?      3.2    ?  
1   19-12-05   ?      1.7    2.6    3.2    0.1
2   19-12-04   0.0    1.7    2.6    3.1    0.1
3   19-12-03   1.5    1.7    2.6    3.2    0.1 
4   19-12-02   1.5    1.8    2.7    3.2    0.1
5   19-12-01   1.5    1.7    ?      ?      0.1
6   19-11-29   1.5    1.7    2.6    3.1    0.1
7   19-11-28   1.6    1.7    2.6    3.2    0.1
8   19-11-27   1.6    1.7    2.6    3.2    0.2
9   19-11-26   1.6    1.7    2.6    3.2    0.2
10  19-11-25   1.5    1.7    2.6    3.2    0.2
11  19-11-24   1.5    1.7    ?      ?      0.2
12  19-11-23   ?      ?      ?      ?      ?
13  19-11-22   1.5    ?      2.6    3.1    ?
14  19-11-21   ?      ?      2.6    ?      ?
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to specify what exactly you want. You have different dates and suddenly in your price cols appear "?". So please ask your question in detail and provide us your trials

Comment: Something like (a) split to different series (one for each country) where the index is the date, (b) join using the index (c) fill the missing values with `?` should work.

Comment: why do you have repeated column names?

Comment: Oh, I am a complete novice at coding, so I really want non-repeated column, but I can't achieve it.

Comment: I sort of understand your logic - you want to resample by min and max dates but your data is wrong - it has errors and repeated column names. Have a think about the question and re-edit it.

Comment: But my row data have repeated column names... Can't I use repeated column names in dataframe?

Comment: I'll think about my question and edit it by tomorrow. I'm really sorry. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is zip each pair and unpair columns and in list comprehension create index by first column, last join together by `concat` and create `DatetimeIndex`

```
a = df.columns[::2]
b = df.columns[1::2]
dfs = [df.loc[:, x].set_index(x[0], drop=False)[x[1]] for x in zip(a, b)]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, sort=False).fillna('?')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%y-%m-%d')
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)

           price1 price2 price1.1 price2.1 price1.2
2019-11-21      ?      ?      2.6        ?        ?
2019-11-22    1.5      ?      2.6      3.1        ?
2019-11-24    1.5    1.7        ?        ?      0.2
2019-11-25    1.5    1.7      2.6      3.2      0.2
2019-11-26    1.6    1.7      2.6      3.2      0.2
2019-11-27    1.6    1.7      2.6      3.2      0.2
2019-11-28    1.6    1.7      2.6      3.2      0.1
2019-11-29    1.5    1.7      2.6      3.1      0.1
2019-12-01    1.5    1.7        ?        ?      0.1
2019-12-02    1.5    1.8      2.7      3.2      0.1
2019-12-03    1.5    1.7      2.6      3.2      0.1
2019-12-04      0    1.7      2.6      3.1      0.1
2019-12-05      ?    1.7      2.6      3.2      0.1
2019-12-06      ?      ?        ?      3.2        ?
```

Comment: Really really Thank you. I'll check your answer soon. It is a midnight here.

Comment: @Mono Meu Elogy Sure, let me know is some problem.

Comment: The Error occurs: TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'

Comment: @Mono Neu Elogy be free remove it, necessary for pandas 0.24+

Comment: But my pandas version is 0.25.3. Should I delete and reinstall it?

Comment: I'll try again tomorrow. Good night jezrael. Thank you so much. See you tomorrow

Comment: This time, new error occurs: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. Good night. It is really time to sleep. Thanks

Comment: @Mono Neu Elogy It means some duplicated datetime, so you can change `dfs = [df.loc[:, x].set_index(x[0], drop=False)[x[1]] for x in zip(a, b)]` to `dfs = [df.loc[:, x].groupby(x[0])[x[1]].sum() for x in zip(a, b)]` for aggregate sum for duplicated datetimes

Comment: Another error occurs **ValueError: time data '1990-01-09' does not match format '%y-%m-%d' (match)**

Comment: I checked all of '1990-01-09' data, but I cannot find any problem...

Comment: My data is a big data. And I found some columns named price3 instead of price1. So I changed them to price1. Then It worked well, but Can't I use the code without changing column name?

Comment: @MonoNeuElogy - You can try to change `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%y-%m-%d')` to `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, yearfirst=True)`

Comment: Oh. I just read your comments. And I tried your code now. And It works perfectly! Thank you so much!