# Pandas: How to set the last rows value of a labeled column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
x = pd.DataFrame([11, 22, 33, 44], columns=['K'])
x
    K
0  11
1  22
2  33
3  44
```

I want to set the value of the last row in column K. This works with a Copy-Warning:

```
x['K'].iloc[-1] = 999
```

I have tried .loc, but -1 is then treated as a label, and since my index is nice (starts at 0, increments by 1), a new row will be created.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If want set by positions is necessary both positions - for index and for columns, so you can get position by column name `K` by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
x.iloc[-1, x.columns.get_loc('K')] = 999
#alternative for set scalar
#x.iat[-1, x.columns.get_loc('K')] = 999
```

Or set by labels with get last value of index (index value has to be unique):

```
x.loc[x.index[-1], 'K'] = 999
#alternative for set scalar
#x.at[x.index[-1], 'K'] = 999
```

Comment: Can you solve my problem? I cannot explain my question...Please help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248820/match-and-rearrange-values-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x.tail(1)['K'] = 999
```

Edit: the above one gives copy warning.

This should work without warning-

```
x.at[x.index[-1],'K'] = 999
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
x.iloc[-1:,:]= 999
```

This is gotten from the argument

```
df.iloc[row_start:row_end , col_start:col_end]
```

Remember to indicate the column number if it is a multiple column dataframe